# update data with segue from UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have a user form that saves information to coreData. I am struggling with the step that will populate the information back into the formViewControll and allow changing information. I have been researching this for a few days and have not been able to implement a working solution. Below is what I've come up with but it does note work. The form ViewController gives this error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'OTSProcess?' The ListVC gives an error: Cannot assign the value of type 'OTSProcessConfirmations' to type 'OTSProcess?'

The Below code allows me to enter and delete values. I am stuggling on the update / edit part where I use delegate to bridge the to two vewController to display the complete information and allow updating.

ViewControll (returns table view of coreData information)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var otsProcessConfirmations: [OTSProcessConfirmation] = []

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return otsProcessConfirmations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let ots = otsProcessConfirmations[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = ots.otsBranch
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(describing: otsProcessConfirmations[indexPath.row].otsDate)

    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // get the data from core data

    getData()


    /// reload the table view

    tableView.reloadData()
}

func getData() {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<OTSProcessConfirmation> = OTSProcessConfirmation.fetchRequest()

    do {
        otsProcessConfirmations = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchRequest)

    }
    catch{
        print("Fetching Failed")
    }

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let context = PersistenceService.context
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        let ots = otsProcessConfirmations[indexPath.row]
        context.delete(ots)

        PersistenceService.saveContext()

        do {
            otsProcessConfirmations = try context.fetch(OTSProcessConfirmation.fetchRequest())
        }
        catch {
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}}
```

form View Controller (I did not include the code that creates the form

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Eureka

class OTSPCViewController: FormViewController {

var otsBranch: String = ""
var otsDate: Date = Date()
var otsComments: String = ""
var otsQ1: Bool = false
var otsQ2: Bool = false
var otsQ3: Bool = false
var otsQ4: Bool = false
var otsQ5: Bool = false
var otsQ6: Bool = false
var otsQ7: Bool = false
var otsQ8: Bool = false
var otsQ9: Bool = false
var otsQ10: Bool = false
var otsQ11: Bool = false
var otsQ12: Bool = false
var otsQ13: Bool = false
var otsQ14: Bool = false


var otsProcessConfirmations = [OTSProcessConfirmation]()

@IBAction func addOTSProcessConfirmation(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    // create the object and add all its parts
    let otsProcessConfirmation = OTSProcessConfirmation(context: PersistenceService.context)

    otsProcessConfirmation.otsBranch = otsBranch
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsDate = otsDate as NSDate
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsComments = otsComments
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ1 = otsQ1
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ2 = otsQ2
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ3 = otsQ3
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ4 = otsQ4
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ5 = otsQ5
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ6 = otsQ6
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ7 = otsQ7
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ8 = otsQ8
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ9 = otsQ9
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ10 = otsQ10
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ11 = otsQ11
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ12 = otsQ12
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ13 = otsQ13
    otsProcessConfirmation.otsQ14 = otsQ14

    // save information to CoreDate
    PersistenceService.saveContext()

}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that your ListViewController is presented by the FormViewController?

Comment: I think we are on the same page. The table view leads to the form (viewController) where a new entry is created and if the user clicks a table cell with an entry then the option to edit the entry should be made available

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for data-flow BACK from a view is through the use of a `delegate`. If you haven't yet, I highly suggest reading up as much as you can on how delegates/protocols work in Swift -- they'll make your life better.

Your current code doesn't adhere to best practices very well (sorry), so I took some liberties with the following, but you'll need to implement it something like this:

FIRST create the delegate:

```
protocol YourDataDelegate: class {
    func updatedData()
}
```

SECOND: Make your presentingViewController adhere to the delegate:

```
extension: ListViewController: YourDataDelegate {
    func updatedData() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

THIRD: Then the delegate to your FormViewController

```
... all your above code...
var OTSProcess:OTSProcess?
weak var delegate: YourDataDelegate?
... all your below code...
```

FOURTH: Set the delegate when you prepare

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let formViewController = segue.destination as? FormViewController  {

        let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let row = indexpath?.row

        formViewController.OTSProcess = OTSs[row!]
        formViewController.delegate = self

    }
 }
}
```

FIFTH AND FINALLY: You need to put a delegate into your FormVC, and have it get called upon whenever that data gets updated:

```
@IBAction func BtnSave(_ sender: Any) {
... all your above code...

delegate?.updatedData()

navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

You can think of this as passing a small part of the bottom viewcontroller to the top viewcontroller, so they can talk to eachother, but in a specific way, but you'd do best to read up on the concept, and clean up the code in here too (lots of force unwrapping...).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I reworked my code and hope it's easier to follow. I am still struggling to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you attempt to implement the delegation solution?

Comment: I was at a loss as I am very new to coding and I’m self thought. I did some searching and will do more tonight